# Paypal API SDK - Error VALIDATION_ERROR NODE

Tags: paypal

I'm developing a system that needs payment using Paypal, but when I return to the url of sucess payments, receiving all the data of my order to update the payment status to Approved, it generates an error, below my successPayments code Controller (Route)

```
`
  

let data = request.all()
  let payerId = data.paymentId
  let paymentId = data.paymentId

  paypal.configure({
     'mode': 'sandbox', //sandbox or live
     'client_id': "",
     'client_secret':''
   });

  let finished = {
        "payer_id": payerId,
        "transactions": [{
            "amount": {
                "currency": "BRL", // BRL
                "total": "1.00"
            }
        }]
    }

  paypal.payment.execute(paymentId, finished,(error,payment)=>{
     if(error){
        console.log(error)
     }else{
        console.log(JSON.stringify(payment))
     }
  })

`
```

Error:

```
response: {
    name: 'VALIDATION_ERROR',
    details: [ [Object] ],
    message: 'Invalid request - see details',
    information_link: 'https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#error-VALIDATION_ERROR',
    debug_id: '7c5d3e9690beb',
    httpStatusCode: 400
  },
  httpStatusCode: 400
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> let payerId = data.paymentId
> ```

The payerId is not a paymentId , but this mistake will not be an issue with the current APIs.

You appear to be using deprecated code such as the [deprecated PayPal-node-SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) that uses the deprecated v1/payments API. Don't do this.

Instead, follow the [current Integrate Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) guide and make 2 routes on your server, one route for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order' (see the optional step 5 in 'Add and modify the code'). You can optionally use [@paypal/checkout-server-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paypal/checkout-server-sdk) on the server. Both of the routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) immediately *before* forwarding your return JSON to the frontend caller.

Pair those 2 routes with the frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Do not use any redirects, redirects are for old websites.